# Error when using redux-persist v6 with redux-persist-transform-immutable v5.0.0

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux-persist

First, I encountered the following installation error,

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: c@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: redux-persist@6.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/redux-persist
npm ERR!   redux-persist@"^6.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer redux-persist@"^4.0.0" from redux-persist-transform-immutable@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/redux-persist-transform-immutable
npm ERR!   redux-persist-transform-immutable@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!
```

Can someone help with this, and explainme why I have this error?

Answer (score 0):

`redux-persist-transform-immutable@5.0.0` package requires `redux-persist@^4.0.0` as its peer dependency, but you have installed `redux-persist@^6.0.0`. The version is incompatible. The warning will display when using npm v7+

Let's check the peer dependencies of `redux-persist-transform-immutable@5.0.0` package:

```
$ npm view redux-persist-transform-immutable@5.0.0 peerDependencies
{ 'redux-persist': '^4.0.0', immutable: '>= 3' }
```

So the safe solution is to downgrade the `redux-persist` package to `^4.0.0`.

```
$ npm i redux-persist@^4.0.0 -S
```

Then, install `redux-persist-transform-immutable`:

```
$ npm i redux-persist-transform-immutable -S
npm WARN deprecated remotedev-serialize@0.1.9: Package moved to @redux-devtools/serialize.

added 4 packages, and audited 9 packages in 912ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The warning is gone. List the installed packages:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
peer-deps-issue@ /home/lindu/workspace/peer-deps-issue
├── redux-persist-transform-immutable@5.0.0
└── redux-persist@4.10.2
```

The last publish time of the `redux-persist-transform-immutable` package is 5 years ago and its latest version is `5.0.0`. It may be outdated and not compatible with the latest version `redux-persist` v6.

Please be careful to run the `npm install <package>` with `--force`, or `--legacy-peer-deps` option, as it will cause potentially broken. Instead, we should fix the version compatibility issues between dependent packages.